# Is there a method for clearing a sheet of data in one call

Tags: c#, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I'm bringing in data from another application, but I don't know what's new and what's updated, so I'm clearing the sheet (row by row - which is time intensive) and re-adding rows.  I'd like to know if there is a way to clear the sheet with one command so that I can re-add my rows.

Keep in mind, My code is in C#.  I do not know cURL or how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single command to delete all rows. However, you can specify a list of rows to delete.
Here is some sample code.

```
var ss = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(accessToken).Build();

var allColumns = ss.SheetResources.ColumnResources.ListColumns(sheetId, null, null);
long primaryColumnId = (long) allColumns.Data.First(c => c.Primary == true).Id;

var columnsToRead = new long[] { primaryColumnId };
Sheet sheet = ss.SheetResources.GetSheet(sheetId, null, null, null, null, columnsToRead, null, null);

var rowsToDelete = sheet.Rows.Select(r => (long) r.Id);

ss.SheetResources.RowResources.DeleteRows(sheetId, rowsToDelete, true);
```

Notes:

- To avoid reading the entire sheet, this sample determines the id for the primary column and only reads that single column.
- If your sheet is huge and you get timeout errors on the delete, you will need to chunk the deletes. (Why? Deleting a row can trigger cascading changes due to cell links, formulas, etc.) If you encounter problems, please let me know and I can update the sample.